# Service available in services.msc but not showing up in "sc query"

Tags: services, jira

I've installed a ticket system, called JIRA. While installing, it offers an option to install JIRA as a service.

Now, when I open up services.msc, I can see the service, and I can also stop and start it. But if I run *sc query* in cmd, it won't list the JIRA service. I've already tried restarting and running the command as an administrator, but it still won't show up.

Can somebody tell me how the service shows up in the managment console, but won't show up on commandline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, problem was that the service was stopped. To show all services, whether running or not, use the following command:

```
sc query state= all
```